# How to hide the body description in homepage in blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, blogger

[This is the description i want to hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnfKi.png)
This is my [blog](http://www.way4telangana.blogspot.com) actually my problem is i want to hide the description in home page and iam using blogger i have tried `color:white` for that it worked but when i moved the description to the top or left the black image displays the description because it is in white color.

And i have also tried `display:none;` but overall code dstruct i mean title moves to some where and image moves to some where i hope understand my problem.

I have heard this can be done with jquery or javascript i mean without css like `display:none;` or `color:white`.

Comment: You'll need to expand on this.. Where is the _description_ on your page? And as a general rule. You should post the code in the question so others have something to read in the future as links can become deprecated.

Comment: ofcourse code is display:none; and color:white; i have added it worked but iam asking whether it is possible with javascript or jquery.?

Comment: All I read was "How to hide the body..."

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**

Comment: do want to hide the description from home page only, or also from search and label pages ?

Comment: I have new blogger theme which has below code:                           
`.widget.Header .header-widget p{
font:$(header.description.font);
font-style:italic;
color:$(header.description.color);
line-height:1.6;
max-width:$(feed.width - 604px);
**display: none;**
}`                                                                                                                                     added line to the Description div css with line bold in above snippet **display: none;** to hide the description from by blogger posts

Answer (score 0):

I found that the descriptions are shown in a div.If You dont want to see that description ,then delete the div from your source.

and if that div is so necessary you add that an `id` or `class` to  particular div and add this css style like this..

```
  <style>
   .desc{
            display: none;  
       }
  </style

  <div class="desc">

   tata capital job openings are there in mumbai it is one of the 
   leading company of the world with our large number of customers
   attracting wide range of customers from all over the world. There are 
   large number of jobs are avilable...
 </div>
```

Comment: thank you vijay iam using blogger platform does body description have widget........? or only div tags....? thanks for that script but it works like css or it works in hidden i mean java script works in hidden.....?

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with editing your html template, here is a solution for you..

Go to **Dashboard** > **Template** > **Edit HTML**

find the div container with class of **post-body** (which contains post discription) and wrap it with blogger `b:if` condition. In this case it will hide the description from all pages except post page and static page.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType in {&quot;static_page&quot;,&quot;item&quot;}'>

    //<div class='post-body entry-content' ...>

    //</div>
</b:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the page break tool in blogger post window.
Just put the page break before every first paragraph/word

Sure this helps